# Differentiability of Implicit Function

Tags: analysis, implicit-differentiation

If we have known $f(x,y)=0$ defines an implicit function $y=g(x)$.

Can we derive $g$ is differentiable from $f$ is differentiable with respect to $x$?

Comment: sounds good. Not sure what does "Can we derive g is differentiable from f is differentiable with respect to x?" mean?

Comment: Implicit function theorem only requires $f$ to be $C^1$, so no.

Comment: I don't want to use implicit function theorem. Assume we have known $f$ defines the implicit function in another way, and $f$ is $C^1$ with respect to $x$, can we prove $g$ is $C^1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $f(x,y)=y/(2+sign(y))-x$ defines the implicit function $y(x) = x(2+sign(x))$, which is not differentiable at $x=0$ even though $f(x,y)$ is $C^1$ in $x$.